# How to have selenium logged in to websites on start up with python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, user-profile

When you open chrome manually, you usually expect your account to stay logged in from last time right?
How do you do that with selenium and python? Currently I'm loading the user profile via the following, and the 'current user' is 'not signed in'

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\ME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\Default")
browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, 
    executable_path='C:\chromedriver.exe')
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.
After I check chrome://version in the python launched instance. The profile there was actually

```
'C:\Users\ME\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default\Default'
```

Notice the two default at the end. To solve it, remove the default for 'user-data-dir'
i.e.

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Users\\ME\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\User Data\\")
```

Answer (score 0):

Hm, looks nice your side
Try adding this 2 lines

```
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation']) 
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["ignore-certificate-errors", "safebrowsing-disable-download-protection", "safebrowsing-disable-auto-update", "disable-client-side-phishing-detection"])
```

Comment: tried, and chrome's current user is still 'not signed in'. This is not the expected behaviour right?

Comment: yes, it should work... did you checked chrome version and chromedriver version and their compatibility?

Comment: aha, I'm noticing space in path -> User Data

Comment: both of them are v86, the chromedriver download link is 'https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/86.0.4240.22/chromedriver_win32.zip' and in chrome://version - '
Google Chrome 86.0.4240.111 (Official Build) (64-bit) (cohort: Stable)'

Comment: is the space not suppose to be there?

Comment: I'm on linux 100% 16y so far on linux they are not making problems, I am not sure what spaces are doing on windows. On OSX I know that they can make problems